# Rearrange plotorder of SpatialPolygonsDataframe

Tags: r, polygon, sp, leaflet-r

I have a SpatialPolygonDataframe (loaded with readOGR) I want to plot in either tmap or leaflet. A lot of the polygons are overlapping, and the smaller polygons are completely covered by larger polygons. Is there a way of rearranging poltorder based on polygonsize?

Sorry for not making a reproducible example…

Comment: Would giving the polygons a transparent fill be enough? If not, my guess is you will have to split your object into several layers.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the plotting order of a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame by assigning to the `plotOrder` slot.

You can use `area` to get the area of each row of a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.

You can use `order` to get a vector that orders its argument.

You can negate such an argument to sort in the right direction.

Hence for some SpatialPolygonsDataFrame with 3 features `ps`:

```
> ps@plotOrder = order(-area(ps))
> plot(ps, col=c(1,2,3)) # colour the three features in the first three colours
```

will plot the smallest last so they show over larger ones.

That's fine for base graphics - I don't know if `leaflet` and `tmap` will respect this. In which case if they are using the order in the data frame, reorder the data frame by decreasing area:

```
ps = ps[order(-area(ps)),]
```

Comment: Passing `leaflet` a data.frame ordered by descending area works!

Comment: @Spacedman, I tested leaflet and it indeeds takes the order in the data frame. Thanks for pointing that out.